# Can refer to an instance of anonymous class?

Tags: java

What I would like to do is to create an instance of anonymous class and be able to refer it like this pseudo example:

```
String s=new String { 
                  //make a subclass,
                  //override method
 }
```

Is this possible?

Comment: The compiler will shoot you if you do this.

Comment: If you need to refer to the class, don't make it *anonymous* :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I understood that the OP wanted to do something like this, but chose a poor class (String) in his example:

```
WindowListener w = new WindowAdapter() {
    public void windowClosing() {
    }
}
```

Now you can refer to an anonymous class (that extends WindowAdapter), through a WindowListener references. Saying that anonymous classes cannot be "refered" is wrong. You can refer to the above instance with `w` and to the class with `w.getClass()`.

Comment: Yes, I forgot that String is final. Not a pro yet.

Answer (score 4):

In particular, you cannot make a subclass of the `String` class, since it's `final`.

And also, anonymous classes **cannot be** refered.

> They are like local classes except that they do not have a name. Use
>   them if you need to use a local class only once.

Comment: +1. As seen in the [docs](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html) - `public final class String extends Object`.

Comment: I don't understand this "anonymous classes cannot be refered". Do you mean you can't refer to anonymous classes?